# Where is classpath from SpringJunit4ClassRunner, and how to point to file in my OS straightly?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, junit

I encountered a problem to access Spring context which is running in my Tomcat from my JUnit (which is running in my workspace).

Demo of my code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:/WEB-INF/applicationContext-resources.xml"
})
public class JUnitAccessSpringContextTest
{
}
```

Unfortunately, above code is not working in my case, because values of my "applicationContext-resources.xml" in my workspace will be replaced before deploying to Tomcat.

Question:

1. What does "classpath" means here?
2. Can I change the "classpath" or append new values here, such as the location of my installed tomcat?

To resolve above problem, an alternative way is to let @ContextConfiguration points to the file directly. It works in my system (shown by the following code), but it is not good for real use because my "path_to_my_tomcat_application" is hard coded.

3. Can I insert some kind of the variable into the @ContextConfiguration "file" String, such as some read String from a property file, or system values through System.getenv(System_parameter_value)?

Change of my code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "file:<path_to_my_tomcat_application>/applicationContext-resources.xml"
})
public class JUnitAccessSpringContextTest
{
}
```

---

Additional information:

To make the things even more complicated. We are running on a old Spring version (2.5) for the project. But I think if necessary, I can change the version spring-test.jar at least -- it should not affect the running project. Am I right?

Comment: WEB-INF isn't on the classpath. If you want to refer to a non-classpath resource, remove the "classpath" part. I'm not convinced they shouldn't stay on the classpath.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for comment! So what does classpath mean indeed? Where is classpath? (I am running Junit from my workspace, not from tomcat installation directory)

Comment: The actual classpath is determined by how you're running it from the workspace. IDEs all have their own mechanism for determining the classpath. If it's a Maven project, in general, the classpath will be whatever the POM defines as dependencies (and all transitive dependencies).

Comment: OK, so it is the classpath of my IDE build. I am using Eclipse without Maven, so the classpath points to the project's "properties/java build path"...

Comment: Then back to the story. The applicationContext-resources.xml is not in the IDE classpath, and it is also not important in my case. Because many parameters in the "applicationContext-resources.xml" need to be changed during the deployment phase -- in this regards, I need to access the "applicationContext-resources.xml" which is already deployed to the Tomcat, whereby all the parameters in "applicationContext-resources.xml" have been updated.

Comment: Therefore, again, I fall into the problem to point to files in Tomcat in ContextConfiguration, because the the Tomcat path is hard coded into the 'locations = { "file:<path_to_tomcat...'

Answer (score 0):

One more alternative way is to set TOMCAT_HOME into the classpath of my Eclipse, and write the relative path into the @ContextConfiguration.

For example, if I set the TOMCAT_HOME/project_name into my Eclipse's classpath, the following code works fine:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:WEB-INF/applicationContext-resources.xml"
})
```

However, because everytime the deployed "project_name" is different from each other, so I cannot put it into my Eclipse path, --> I can only put the entire tomcat home (TOMCAT_HOME) into my Eclipse classpath. But in this case, the following code does NOT work. why?

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:*/WEB-INF/applicationContext-resources.xml"
})
```

Thanks!